# Activity Recognition does not work in Android For Work

Tags: android, activity-recognition, android-for-work

I have an app which requests activity updates via the ActivityRecognition API. When I load it on a device with Android For Work, the work version of the app never gets activity updates, but the personal version works fine.

I'm checking the result from `requestActivityUpdates()` as shown below, and I get success, but never actually get any activity intents.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BreakTimeMonitor.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_DETECT_ACTIVITY);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Register for activity updates
    PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(
            googleApiClient,
            DETECTION_INTERVAL,
            pendingIntent);
    pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error requesting activity updates: " + status.getStatusCode() + "," + status.getStatusMessage());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Request for activity updates successful: " + status.getStatusCode() + "," + status.getStatusMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:** The manifest does have an entry for the BreakTimeMonitor service, so that's not the issue. I've also tried adding a different user account to see if that worked, and it did - so it's just the work account that doesn't work.

Comment: Have you declared your BreakTimeMonitor service in the manifest file?

Comment: Yes, I have. It's also working fine from the non-work app.